# CopyCommand Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-s3, copy, command, amazon-redshift

I have JSON like below -

```
{
"Col1" : "Value1",
"Col2" : "Value2",
"Col3"  : "Value3"
}
{
"Col1" : "Value100",
"Col2" : "Value200",
"Col3"  : "Value300"
}
{
"ColX" : "Hello",
"ColY" : "World"
}
```

When I try to load the data into the table using copy command, its gets loaded in the below format -

[Table_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h13Gx.png)

But, I want to load the data in the below format.

[Required_Table_Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qACUf.png)

Is there any way to achieve my Objective using copy command ?

(I can use temp tables if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do so using `copy` command, because it maps one line in the input data to one row in the Redshift table.

You might have to post-process your data after the `copy` command, to achieve your objective.